# NuGet packages get stale? "Failed to download package correctly. The contents of the package could not be verified"

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

We're experiencing a strange issue with our local NuGet package server.  Over time, it appears that packages become unavailable, **and the only fix seems to be touching the .nupkg file** (e.g., just opening the file in Package Explorer) or just create a new build / version of the package.

Here's a picture of the error that comes back:

[image: Failed to verify package contents]

We're using IIS6 to host the NuGet server, using the latest NuGet packages for the server (server and core version 1.5.20902.9026)

**Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it for good?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a bug in NuGet.Server. There's a race condition that causes the feed to get a stale hashcode. You can follow the various discussions about it on nuget.

- http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/272898
- http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/278108

Answer (score 9):

We came across this on our Jenkins build server all of a sudden, Entity Framework could not be downloaded by NuGet. In our case the problem was that the **NuGet.exe** that was checked in along with the project itself hadn't been updated in quite some time.

I solved this the following way:

- Checked out the project from version control
- Opened a command prompt and navigated to the **.nuget** subfolder in the project
- Ran the following command to let NuGet.exe update itself: `NuGet.exe update -self`
- In our case this resulted in v1.6 getting updated to v2.7.3 so we have been sloppy :)
- Checked in the replaced NuGet.exe in version control

After that the project built just fine again. I think we will investigate the possibility to not check in NuGet.exe in the future, this SO post seems to be helpful but I haven't been able to try it myself yet : [Prevent needing to add NuGet.exe to source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022154/prevent-needing-to-add-nuget-exe-to-source-control)

Comment: I did got exactly the same prb, but when using the Nuget.Core and programmatically getting packages.

Comment: I used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057812/2735163

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was trying to install T4Scaffolding, and I was able to solve it by re-installing NuGet Package Manager (as I wasn't able update the package manager, I uninstalled, and re-installed).