# Prevent needing to add NuGet.exe to source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, nuget

**Some context:**
I've followed the [tutorial on using NuGet without committing packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) with some success. After working around [this NuGet issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1879) by manually adding `<RestorePackages>` and a `<Import ...>` for the nuget.targets file things were working.

However, once I cloned the repository with Mercurial, I got the following error when building:

> Unable to locate 'C:\...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\.nuget\nuget.exe'

This makes sense, because my ignore pattern prevented me from checking in the exe file. From [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10111441/419956) I inferred that it's not uncommon to have this file in version control (or is it?), but really I'd **prefer not to commit NuGet.exe to version control** if I can help it.

---

***Question:*** Is there a convenient way to prevent needing to check in NuGet.exe?

---

I've tried some Google-fu, skimming the documentation, and fiddling with the NuGet.targets file, no luck so far. It seems preferable if I could just dynamically point to the NuGet.exe of the particular environment that's building the solution.

I know I could just add the exe file, but I'd prefer to know if there are other ways to handle this or know why there are no viable alternatives.

**Update:**
The nuget.targets file holds some relevant xml:

```xml
<!-- only (relevant) parts of the xml shown below -->
<DownloadNuGetExe Condition=" '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == '' ">false</DownloadNuGetExe>
...
<UsingTask TaskName="DownloadNuGet" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <Task>
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
        try {
            OutputFilename = Path.GetFullPath(OutputFilename);

            Log.LogMessage("Downloading latest version of NuGet.exe...");
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile("https://nuget.org/nuget.exe", OutputFilename);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.LogErrorFromException(ex);
            return false;
        }
        ]]>
        </Code>
    </task>
</UsingTask>
```

I'm unfamiliar with the workings of .targets files, but this seems to be along the lines of what I'm looking for. With my cowboy-coding hat on I tried changing the `false` to `true` in the DownloadNuGetExe element, but this didn't work as expected (with or without the condition attribute).

Comment: You can also delete .nuget folder and edit project file and after this you can start app.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Just checked: nuget.targets is an msbuild file. And you were on the right way, in:

```xml
<DownloadNuGetExe Condition=" '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == '' ">false</DownloadNuGetExe>
```

Change the value to true:

```xml
<DownloadNuGetExe Condition=" '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == '' ">true</DownloadNuGetExe>
```

But you must **restart Visual Studio or reload the solution (see comments)** after this to take effect.

Comment: Oh my lord. Can't believe the solution was to restart VS! (Why is that, anyway?) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem. It looks like a bug that VS doesn't track changes in files which linked to csproj files and don't ask for reload.

Comment: You don't need to restart VS, just reload the solution to cause the projects to be re-read.

Comment: @shambulator thx for the tip, I've updated the answer so future visitors can easily spot that solution

Comment: Visual Studio uses *extremely* agressive cacheing of solution and project files (and also / especially msbuild project files loaded via import).When changing msbuild files, you can test them from command line immidiately and when finished re-load the corresponding project(s) in VS:

Comment: I just used this, and VS2013 did not require a restart. Maybe it's been updated to better watch the file?

Comment: Just restarted Visual Studio and that solved my problem... Thanks!

Comment: with VS 2015 followed the instructions: change NuGet.targets, removed .exe, restarted VS but NuGet.exe appears in working directory after rebuild! I am about to include it to the .gitignore even it is not included in common/recommended ignore files for VS. Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

Looking at that `.targets` file, there's another way to do this if you neither want to check `NuGet.exe` in, nor download it every time. The key line is this:

```xml
<NuGetExePath Condition=" '$(NuGetExePath)' == '' ">$(NuGetToolsPath)\nuget.exe</NuGetExePath>
```

Following the MSBuild convention of only setting properties if they haven't already been defined, this value defaults to the solution's local copy of `NuGet.exe`, downloading it if the `DownloadNuGetExe` property is `true`. But MSBuild properties can be overridden by environment variables.

If you already have NuGet downloaded to some central location, you can leave `DownloadNuGetExe` at `false` and define an environment variable called `NUGETEXEPATH`, which will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Enable NuGet Package Restore
[image]

Right click on solution then select **Enable NuGet Package Restore**

Comment: This does not really answer my question, right? In the first article I mention this exact instruction is included too, i.e. with my question you can assume I already *have* enabled package restore. My question is about getting `nuget.exe` when it's missing.

Comment: Yes.Excuse me!. I think you need to add NuGet Package for you solution