# Is there a connection between nuget.config and gui settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-server

When trying to generate a build, I am getting the following error:

```
1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
$/source control my solution....../Web.sln - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File
 D:\Builds\.....zWeb\.nuget\NuGet.targets (93): The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

I am configuring the repository URLs both here:
[image]

And in the NuGet.config file:

[image]

I've tried the following:

1. tried multiple network connections (to rule out firewall issues)
2. restarted VS and reinstalled NuGet and all packages
3. cleaned, rebuilt
4. changed the [downloadnuget setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932154/unable-to-locate-nuget-exe-when-building-webservice-on-appharbor)

**What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to build?**

In case it is relevant, here's my [nuget.targets](http://pastebin.com/cmcuVrFA) file.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to place file nuget.config 
in root of your solution like

x:\SolutionFolder\nuget.config
x:\SolutionFolder\Web.sln

then change `nuget.config`
to have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Your NuGet" value="\\YourServer\Nuget Gallery" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

the repositoryPath is relative to nuget.config file localization
create this network share and be sure that your use have access to it

```
<add key="Your NuGet" value="\\YourServer\Nuget Gallery" />
```

What tfs version and visual studio version you use localy and on the build server ?