# Error initializing task DownloadNuGet: Not registered task DownloadNuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mono, nuget, xbuild

I am attempting to compile by C# application using Mono on Ubuntu. I am trying to prevent the need to include `nuget.exe` in my git repository and have followed the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022154/prevent-needing-to-add-nuget-exe-to-source-control)

This works if I am using Visual Studio 2010. When I build the application, nuget.exe is downloaded as expected.

However, when I attempt to use mono and xbuild, I receive the following error.

```
Target Build:
    Project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/BuildTrade/BuildTrade.csproj" (default target(s)):
    Target CheckPrerequisites:
        Project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/.nuget/NuGet.targets" (_DownloadNuGet target(s)):
            Target _DownloadNuGet:
: error : Error initializing task DownloadNuGet: Not registered task DownloadNuGet.
            Task "DownloadNuGet" execution -- FAILED
            Done building target "_DownloadNuGet" in project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/.nuget/NuGet.targets".-- FAILED
        Done building project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/.nuget/NuGet.targets".-- FAILED
    Task "MsBuild" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "CheckPrerequisites" in project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/BuildTrade/BuildTrade.csproj".-- FAILED
    Done building project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/BuildTrade/BuildTrade.csproj".-- FAILED
Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "Build" in project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/SpecialBuildProj.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/home/builduser/SpecialBuildProj/SpecialBuildProj.sln".-- FAILED
```

The only thing I've changed is setting `DownloadNuGetExe` = `true` in `nuget.targets`, so that line looks like this:

```
<DownloadNuGetExe Condition=" '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == '' ">true</DownloadNuGetExe>
```

**My question:**
How can I set it so that the behavior using mono/xbuild is the same as when using Visual Studio (namely, that nuget is downloaded automatically)?

**Edit**
This is the `UsingTask` line that appears in the `NuGet.targets` file.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="DownloadNuGet" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
        <OutputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Using Namespace="System" />
        <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
        <Using Namespace="System.Net" />
        <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Framework" />
        <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Utilities" />
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            <![CDATA[
            try {
                OutputFilename = Path.GetFullPath(OutputFilename);

                Log.LogMessage("Downloading latest version of NuGet.exe...");
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile("https://nuget.org/nuget.exe", OutputFilename);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.LogErrorFromException(ex);
                return false;
            }
        ]]>
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a script to download it.  E.g.

```
wget http://nuget.org/nuget.exe
cp nuget.exe ./.nuget/NuGet.exe
chmod a+x ./.nuget/NuGet.exe
```

This keeps your NuGet.exe up to date. [Source](http://dlafferty.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/building-your-microsoft-solution-with.html)

Comment: Downloading NuGet.exe manually helped me get one step forward in using NuGet with xbuild. The immediate next problem was that NuGet.exe couldn't download packages due to untrusted certificates. The solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181888/nuget-on-linux-error-getting-response-stream

Answer (score 0):

This continues to be a problem today with Xamarin Studio for Business and MacOS. I encountered this error while trying to build the Facebook SDK. I had to remove the NuGet target references in the project file to make the project build. Xamarin Studio has the NuGet update built into it, so I was able to download the packages manually.