# Failed to download package 'runtime.win10-x86.Microsoft.Net.UWPCoreRuntimeSdk.2.1.1'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, nuget

I'm working with Mobile App in Visual Studio 2017, but when I first created this project and tried to build it, the following error occurred:

```
Failed to download package 'runtime.win10-x86.Microsoft.Net.UWPCoreRuntimeSdk.2.1.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk/2.1.1/runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk.2.1.1.nupkg'.
The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk/2.1.1/runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk.2.1.1.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
```

I searched and found someone suggesting I should change my DNS server from 8.8.8.8 to 208.67.222.222 but it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: URL doesn't timeout in Firefox for me. Try opening cmd and running`tracert api.nuget.org`? Did you ever use your HOSTS file/etc to block Microsoft tracking?

Comment: I opened this url in google chrome and doesn't timeout. what you mean by HOSTS file. Can you provide me a link to explain this.

Comment: If the URL isn't timing out in Chrome, HOSTS file is not causing your issues. (It's a means of redirecting domains, for example to redirect Microsoft tracking domains to an invalid server. )

Comment: Until now, I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

Comment: I had this problem when trying to upgrade the UWP nuget package `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` from version 6.2.9 to 6.2.10, @Michael's workaround worked

Answer (score 24):

I hit this issue as well for all my packages.  But if I copied the nupkg link to my browser, I could download the package fine.  So it was an issue with VS somewhere.  I filed a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/420352/nuget-download-timeouts.html).

To workaround it, as no other solutions I found seemed to work, I downloaded nuget.exe from the [Nuget Download page](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then ran the following in the command line:

```
nuget restore MySolution.sln
```

This downloaded all the packages fine.  Once it was done, I could run my project in VS without problems.

Comment: you work for Microsoft and this bug has not been solved yet???

Comment: @knocte Microsoft is a big place with tens of thousands of engineers. I don't work in this area, so I don't have the capability to fix the underlying issue. I just also encountered the problem throughout the course of my day job and posted how I worked around it here for others benefit. I filed a bug on the issue, but it was closed. I'll re-raise it with the NuGet team to raise awareness.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should fix the problem yourself :) but make some noise yeah ;)

Comment: @knocte if you're seeing this problem yourself, can you follow the instructions in Rob's note here and provide some logs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60857379/8798708 Thanks!

Comment: but I don't think this is a nuget bug, given that this workaround works; it should be a VS bug

Comment: This works for me. I tried seeking this solution. I almost failed because my solution name have a white space. I renamed it and run well. Just wonder, run "dotnet restore" in VS dont works because of time running out.

Answer (score 3):

> Failed to download package 'runtime.win10-x86.Microsoft.Net.UWPCoreRuntimeSdk.2.1.1'

According to the error log, this issue should be more related to the internet connection, but since change DNS server not work for you and you can open that url in google chrome without timeout, I would like provide you a workaround for this issue.

**Workaround:**

Download the package `runtime.win10-x86.Microsoft.Net.UWPCoreRuntimeSdk.2.1.1` from the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.win10-x86.Microsoft.Net.UWPCoreRuntimeSdk/) manually.

[image]

Add this package to the folder: `C:\Users\<UserName>\.nuget\packages`

Then you can build your project without that issue.

Comment: but in that folder there are no .nupkg files but subfolders

Answer (score 2):

Just retry. It seem to be related to slow Internet connection or server side overload and you will finally succeed.

Answer (score 0):

We will need additional information in order to investigate. Please follow the instructions in the nuget.org FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/nuget-org-faq#nugetorg-not-accessible to gather logs and contact the team as mentioned in the FAQ.